# What is the difference between optimization and optimal control?

Tags: optimization, terminology, optimal-control

What is the difference between optimization and optimal control? I am trying to understand the difference between those two, but it is still confusing to me. Could anyone please explain it briefly?

Comment: Optimization is more general. Optimal control is merely one application of optimization.

Comment: Much of optimal control is *infinite*-dimensional optimization.